# React-Native-Navigation changing state in other screen with getParam()

Tags: react-native, state, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I want to navigate to Decrease screen from Home screen and after entering a number into TextInput send it to change **total** in Home screen by using ```getParam('clickMe','changeTotal')`` but I couldn't find a way to pass **number** to Home screen.

Home.Js

```
export default class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    total: 1000
  };

  decreaseTotalHandlerNavigate = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Decrease", { clickMe: this.changeTotal });
  };

  changeTotal = number => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ total: prevState.total - number }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{this.state.total}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.decreaseTotalHandlerNavigate}>
          <Text>Decrease</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Decrease.js

```
export default class Decrease extends Component {
  state = {
    number: 0
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TextInput
          onChangeText={value => {
            this.setState({
              number: value
            });
          }}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.navigation.getParam("clickMe", "changeTotal")}>
          <Text>Add</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you pass ```total``` value with ```this.props.navigation.navigate("Decrease", { total: this.state.total})``` & do your calculation inside Decrease screen.

Comment: I want to change state  from Decrease screen. So how can I pass the result to Home screen if I do the calculation in Decrease screen ?

Comment: you can achieve that in multiple ways. if you can describe your scenario with details I might be able to help you with a sample code.

Comment: It's simple,user will navigate to Decrease screen from Home screen and after entering a number by clicking the button the number will be subtracted from total and new total will be shown in the Home screen.

Comment: You too could use the `setParams` method to set on Home Screen